# How to apply threshold to segment grey region out from the image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Sample Image:

[image: 1]

Here's my code

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 


image = cv2.imread("1.bmp")

img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img_grey,120,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_grey,120,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

cv2.imshow("image 1", thresh1)
cv2.imshow("image 2", thresh)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Any idea to segment the grey region ? I thought some sort of subtracting the white and black region using raw image but not working.

Answer (score 3):

#### Option 1:

You need to place **different** threshold values but the **same** binary operation. Then try subtracting the result:

```
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img_grey,20,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img_grey,235,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

result = thresh1 - thresh2

cv2.imshow("Result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

See the images of `thresh1` and `thresh2` to understand what's going on.

And if you are worried about how to subtract use cv2.subtract(), it handles pixel range:

```
result2 = cv2.subtract(thresh1, thresh2)
cv2.imshow("Result2", result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The output does not provide the desired result.

#### Option 2:

You can also use [multi-Otsu threshold module available from skimage](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_multiotsu.html). This module provides threshold values based on the number of regions you want to segment the image.

- If you want to segment the image into 3 regions (A, B, C), the function gives you 2 threshold values (t1, t2).

  - 0 - t1 `-->` region A
  - t1 - t2 `-->` region B
  - t2 - 255 `-->` region C

The same can be extended for any number of regions, but the function takes more time to calculate threshold values for regions greater than 5.

*Number of Threshold values = Number of regions - 1*

**Code:**

```
# import the module
from skimage.filters import threshold_multiotsu

im = cv2.imread('cells.png', 0)
# create black screen of same image shape
b = np.zeros(im.shape, np.uint8)

# find threshold values for 3 regions
thresholds = threshold_multiotsu(im,3)
print(thresholds)
>>> [ 65 189]     # 2 threshold values

# finding average value 
mean = int(np.mean(thresholds))
b[im == mean] = 255
```

[image]

> Option 2 would be a more statistical way of determining threshold value for any image

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways to do that in Python/OpenCV/Numpy.  The first method uses cv2.inRange() color thresholding. The second method use Numpy. Both threshold so that the gray region becomes white and the rest black.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read input
img = cv2.imread("white_gray_black.png")

# Method 1 Use cv2.inRange
low = (127,127,127)
high = (127,127,127)
mask1 = cv2.inRange(img, low, high)
cv2.imwrite("white_gray_black_mask1.png",mask1)

# Method 2 Use Numpy
mask2 = img.copy()
mask2[img==127] = 255
mask2[img!=127 ] = 0
cv2.imwrite("white_gray_black_mask2.png",mask2)

cv2.imshow('mask1', mask1)
cv2.imshow('mask2', mask2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result 1:

[image]

Result 2:

[image]

If you need to preserve the gray, then the second method is easier.

```
# Method 3 Use Numpy
mask3 = img.copy()
mask3[img!=127] = 0
cv2.imwrite("white_gray_black_mask3.png",mask3)

cv2.imshow('mask3', mask3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```